# Who gets magic if the Fallen Kingdom Ghoul destroys itself?

Tags: summoner-wars

The card states:

> if the Ghoul did not destroy a Unit during that Attack Phase, place 1
>   Wound Marker on this card

In the scenario that the Ghoul is destroyed as a result of having a wound placed on it in this manner, who gets the magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner gets it, since it was their ability that destroyed the card.

Comment: So the general rule is that if a cards ability destroys a unit, the owner of the card with said ability gets the magic?

Comment: I think that follows, yes.